# Exercise 5, Section 2.4 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing

> Let $\alpha=(x_1,x_2)$ and $\beta =(y_1,y_2)$ be vector in $\Bbb{R}^2$ such that $x_1y_1 +x_2y_2=0$ and $x_1^2+x_2^2=y_1^2+y_2^2=1$. Prove that $B=\{\alpha ,\beta\}$ is basis of $\Bbb{R}^2$. Find the coordinate of the vector $(a,b)$ in the ordered basis $B=\{\alpha , \beta\}$.

**My attempt:** If $c_1\cdot \alpha +c_2\cdot \beta=(0,0)$, for some $c_1,c_2\in \Bbb{R}$. Then $c_1\cdot (x_1,x_2)+c_2\cdot (y_1,y_2)$ $=(c_1x_1, c_1x_2)+(c_2y_1,c_2y_2)$ $=(c_1x_1+c_2y_1,c_1x_2+c_2y_2)$ $=(0,0)$. So $c_1x_1+c_2y_1=0$ and $c_1x_2+c_2y_2=0$. Square both equation, $(c_1x_1+c_2y_1)^2$ $=c_1^2 x_1^2 +c_2^2 y_1^2 +2c_1c_2x_1y_1$ $=0$ and $(c_1x_2+c_2y_2)^2$ $=c_1^2 x_2^2 +c_2^2 y_2^2+2c_1c_2x_2y_2$ $=0$. Add both equation, $(c_1^2 x_1^2 +c_2^2 y_1^2 +2c_1c_2x_1y_1)+(c_1^2 x_2^2 +c_2^2 y_2^2+2c_1c_2x_2y_2)$ $=c_1^2 (x_1^2 +x_2^2)+c_2^2 (y_1^2+y_2^2)+2c_1c_2(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)$ $=0$. Since $x_1y_1 +x_2y_2=0$ and $x_1^2+x_2^2=y_1^2+y_2^2=1$, we have $c_1^2+c_2^2+2c_1c_2(0)=c_1^2+c_2^2=0$. Which implies $c_1=c_2=0$. Hence $B=\{\alpha ,\beta\}$ is independent. We claim $\alpha \neq \beta$. Assume towards contradiction, $\alpha$ $=\beta$ $=(x_1,x_2)$ $=(y_1,y_2)$. So $x_1=y_1$ and $x_2=y_2$. Since $x_1y_1 +x_2y_2=0$, we have $x_1^2+x_2^2=0$. But $x_1^2+x_2^2=1$. Thus we reach contradiction. So $|B|=2$. By theorem 4 corollary 2 section 2.3, $\mathrm{span}(B)=\Bbb{R}^2$. Hence $B$ is basis of $\Bbb{R}^2$. **Is my proof correct?**

Let $(a,b)\in \Bbb{R}^2$. We need to find $(c_1,c_2)\in \Bbb{R}^2$ such that $(a,b)=c_1\cdot \alpha+c_2\cdot \beta$. So $c_1x_1+c_2y_1=a$ and $c_1x_2+c_2y_2=b$. Square both equation, $(c_1x_1+c_2y_1)^2$ $=c_1^2 x_1^2 +c_2^2 y_1^2 +2c_1c_2x_1y_1$ $=a^2$ and $(c_1x_2+c_2y_2)^2$ $=c_1^2 x_2^2 +c_2^2 y_2^2+2c_1c_2x_2y_2$ $=b^2$. Add both equation, $(c_1^2 x_1^2 +c_2^2 y_1^2 +2c_1c_2x_1y_1)+(c_1^2 x_2^2 +c_2^2 y_2^2+2c_1c_2x_2y_2)$ $=c_1^2 (x_1^2 +x_2^2)+c_2^2 (y_1^2+y_2^2)+2c_1c_2(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)$ $=a^2+b^2$. Since $x_1y_1 +x_2y_2=0$ and $x_1^2+x_2^2=y_1^2+y_2^2=1$, we have $c_1^2+c_2^2+2c_1c_2(0)$ $=c_1^2+c_2^2$ $=a^2 +b^2$. **How to solve $c_1^2+c_2^2= a^2 +b^2$ equation?** Obviously $(c_1,c_2)=(a,b)$ is one of the solution. So $(a,b)$ is coordinate of $(a,b)$ relative to ordered basis $B=\{\alpha ,\beta\}$. **Is it enough to prove this problem?**